# Windows batch - move x amount of folders+content to another folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory, move

I am in the process of cleaning up and organizing my NAS folders.

However, I have folder with over 1800+ folder in it, I need to have this split into 18 folders each containing maximum 100 folders. The name of the folder they are moved to is irrelevant, but at top-level should be sequential. All folder content should be moved along.

Additionally, I need a batch file which also reverses this.

The reason this is needed is due to the program I uses to index and organize my folders and folder content with cannot handle easily folders with more than 100 folders.

I tried myself already, but ended up foobar'ing it completely.

Comment: You should show some own research.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
@ECHO OFF

SET destination=c:\temp\
SET source=c:\windows\system32\
SET dcount=0
SET fcount=0
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

MKDIR %destination%dir%dcount%


FOR /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('DIR /b /s /a:d "%source%*"') do (
  SET str=%%f
  SET str=!str:%source%=!
  MKDIR %destination%dir!dcount!\!str!
  COPY %%f %destination%dir!dcount!\!str! 1> NUL
  SET /a fcount=!fcount!+1
  IF !fcount! EQU 100 (
    SET fcount=0
    SET /a dcount=!dcount!+1
    MKDIR %destination%dir!dcount!
  )
)

ECHO DONE.
```

Obviously source and destination will need to be changed, and there is no attempt to sanity check or fail gracefully from errors...

**EDIT :**

The first version recursively descends all sub-directories and moves each them into the new structure--basically destroying their internal nesting and organization.  This second one preserves the internal structures of the subdirectories nested inside of source directory's immediate subdirectories...  Take your pick.

```
@ECHO OFF

SET destination=c:\temp\
SET source=c:\windows\system32\
SET dcount=0
SET fcount=0
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

MKDIR %destination%dir%dcount%


FOR /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('DIR /b /a:d "%source%*"') do (
  MKDIR %destination%dir!dcount!\%%f
  XCOPY %source%%%f %destination%dir!dcount!\%%f /e /y 
  SET /a fcount=!fcount!+1
  IF !fcount! EQU 100 (
    SET fcount=0
    SET /a dcount=!dcount!+1
    MKDIR %destination%dir!dcount!
  )
)

ECHO DONE.
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in my limited test and creates an `UNDO.BAT` to restore the folders to where they were.  Test it for yourself to be sure it does what you want.

The value `num` is the number of folders you want in each top level folder

`f` is used to create the holding folders - 001, 002, 003 etc

Launch it in the folder with all the subdirectories to be moved.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set num=100
set c=0
set f=1001
set folder=%f:~-3%
del undo.bat 2>nul
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a:d /o:n /b') do (
set /a c=c+1
   md !folder! 2>nul
   move "%%a" !folder!
   echo move "!folder!\%%a" "%cd%" ^& rd !folder! 2^>nul >>undo.bat
    if !c! EQU %num% (
      set c=0
      set /a f=f+1
      set folder=!f:~-3!
    )
)
```